# cookie is showing null value for first time and after coming again to that page, i can see cookie value. Asp.net c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, cookies, paypal

I am developing a website in which user has to buy a subscription, what i am trying to do is that when user log in to my website for buying subscription i save his/her email id in a cookie and then he/she is redirected to paypal and after paying money he comes back to success page of my website and there i retrieves the cookie of his email id to update database but there for first time i gets null value and if i repeat the same process again i can read the value in cookie which i stored. On my localhost this problem wasn't coming but when i published the website this problem came. help me out
The code i am using to store the cookie

```
Response.Cookies["useremail"].Value = Session["user_id"].ToString();
Response.Cookies["useremail"].Expires = DateTime.Now.AddDays(1);
```

The code i am using to retrieve the cookie

```
if (Request.Cookies["useremail"] != null)
      Label1.Text= Server.HtmlEncode(Request.Cookies["useremail"].Value);
```

On the browser i have seen that cookie is saved.

Comment: if you already have the value stored in the Session then in your if statement why don't you check `if(string.IsNullOrEmpty(Session["user_id"].ToString()))` instead..?

Comment: if anyone need further information i can provide that, i followed this link to work with cookies https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178194.aspx

Comment: @MethodMan i have also tried with session, when user came to success page after paying in paypal, the session in my website was ended, even i didnt put any restrictions on session time, thats why i loose the information in session object.

Comment: why don't you post all relevant code in regards to you saying you followed the link.. I don't see anywhere where you are declaring the HttpCookie Object in your code based on the link example you provided..

Comment: if your Session Expired then you need to configure the Session TimeOuts do you have access to a web admin or someone that knows IIS or whatever webserver you are using..?

Comment: @MethodMan the funny part is that the same was the problem with session too that for first time session didnt exist and when i repeat the process again session existed that i could read values that i stored in session variable.

Comment: i am using plesk as my server interface, if you guide me i can change the settings

Comment: do you use `Global.asax` page in your web app.. if so on Session_Start this is where you should be initializing any of your Session variables initially for example `HttpContext.Current.Session["user_id"] = string.Empty;`

Comment: In the link this was an option too that i showed here in code part.

Comment: I do not know Plesk so sounds like you should do a google search on how to increase or set SessionTimeout using Plesk..

Comment: yes i have initialized the variables in global.asax, same as you said.

Comment: also there is a major difference between accessing Session["user_id"] vs `HttpContext.Current.Session[user_id"]` the Session["user_id"] at run time will have more of a tendency to error.. you can read up on it if you do a google search

Comment: @MethodMan i just want to retrieve the information of person in success page who logged in to my website, so can you help me with that in regards with cookie.

Comment: kind of hard to help you when you don't show any code in regards to the success page.. if you are going to post code as well as ask a question please present all relevant code that pertains to your current situation also how are you passing the variables to the Success Page.. have you thought about using / passing QuertString values to the Success Page and checking the values etc.... there are plenty of ways of doing this I personally think cookies are not a good option ...this is my personal opinion...

Comment: i cant use query string because paypal redirects to my success page and the code if (Request.Cookies["useremail"] != null)
      Label1.Text= Server.HtmlEncode(Request.Cookies["useremail"].Value);        i used to retrieve the info of cookie nothing else, other code is sql query to update user data

Comment: also I do not see where you are actually adding the Cookie to the Response Object for example `HttpContext.Response.Cookies.Add("Your Cookie Object");`

Comment: No i only used Response.Cookies["useremail"].Value="abcd" to initialize a cookie because its in the link that you can also build a cookie by only doing this, however i try to use you suggested and tell you :)

Comment: Did you ever solve this issue? I have the exact same problem in .NET CORE 3.1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In a nutshell this is what I would expect to see in your code but I do not so you can try this and replace it with the proper variables etc to make your code work.
I test this on my test server and it works so you can follow the same pattern.

```
string myCookieName = "abcd";
HttpCookie aCookie = new HttpCookie(myCookieName);
aCookie.Value = DateTime.Now.ToString();
aCookie.Expires = DateTime.Now.AddDays(1);
Response.Cookies.Add(aCookie);
```

Comment: i appreciate your help, provided code didn't worked for me however i am trying different logic now :) Thanks mate

Comment: If I saw your full code I could get it to work in regards to how you are passing things ..also take a look to make sure you are not doing full postbacks or maybe look into implementing Update Panels to take advantage of partial postbacks.. cheers..